# How to send python post requests with a $ in the form data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send form data with a post request, but one of my data headers has a $ in the name which python doesn't like. How can I get around this?

```
payload = dict(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_ClientState='{"ActiveTabIndex":3,"TabState":[true,true,true,true]}',
           ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TC1TP1$DropDownList1_1='250 per page')

s = requests.Session()
donor_page = s.post(url, files=payload)
```

I need to send that second data field with the $ included. I don't know if I am going about this the complete wrong way or what, I'm new to python and requests. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use the `{}` dict syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **dictionary literal** or set such header after constructing the dict using `[]`:

```
# dictionary literal
payload = { 
  'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_ClientState': '{"ActiveTabIndex":3,"TabState":[true,true,true,true]}',
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TC1TP1$DropDownList1_1': '250 per page'
}

# or assign later
payload = dict(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_ClientState='{"ActiveTabIndex":3,"TabState":[true,true,true,true]}')
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TC1TP1$DropDownList1_1'] = '250 per page'

s = requests.Session()
donor_page = s.post(url, files=payload)
```